# Обрабока нажатия кнопки в fragment

Tags: java, android

Имею код:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragments2, null, false);
button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        return v;
}
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "123!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
```

При нажатии кнопки выдает ошибку.В чем проблема?

Comment: Если вы назначаете слушатель кликов через разметку xml (атрибут `android:onClick`),то это работает только для активити. В фрагментах можно использовать только программную установку слушателя через реализацию интерфейса `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если таким способом, то наверное в методе onCreateView нужно вызвать метод OnClink и передать ему параметр button. То есть:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragments2, null, false);
button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
onClick(button);
        return v;
}
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "123!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

В таком случае при создании фрагмента будет выводится "123!".
Если вы хотите что бы при нажатии на кнопку проводились действия то лучше всего использовать `setOnClickListener()`.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragments2, null, false);
button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Ваши действия
        }
    });
        return v;
}
```

Comment: Теперь при запуске выдает 1 раз сообщение:123!. Но если нажать кнопку, то вылетает

Comment: @Сашка изменил ответ... Пробуйте

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NameFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragments2, null, false);
button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            "123!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

}
```

Comment: Я пытался через xml, но он не предлагает почему-то создать.Почем-то ругается на строчку `button.setOnClickListener(this);` Пишет:`Error:(107, 35) error: incompatible types: fragments2 cannot be converted to OnClickListener`

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, посмотрите